# How to get a value from a session in a php file from another php file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a cookie in a php file using $_Session and after that I want to redirect the user to another page. Within the new page, I want to display the user's information such as their first name.

In doing so, I figured I would need two php files, and I need to connect the two.

here is my first php file ('contactform.php')

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])){
    session_start();
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $occupation = $_POST['dropdown'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $hearaboutus = $_POST['hearaboutus'];

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstName;
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
    $_SESSION['emailFrom'] = $emailFrom;
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $firstNaphoneme;
    $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
    $_SESSION['occupation'] = $occupation;
    $_SESSION['age'] = $age;
    $_SESSION['hearaboutus'] = $hearaboutus;

    $mailTo = "ate@gmail.com";
    $subjectLine = "E-Mail From: ".$emailFrom."; www.ate.com";
    $emailBody = "You have received an email from ".$firstName."\n\n".$message."\n\n\n";

    mail($mailTo, $subjectLine, $emailBody);
    header("Location: thankupage.php");

    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

and here is my second php file

```
<?php
    include 'contactform.php';
    echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
    echo Hii;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Thanks</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

it seems to me that

```
include 'contactform.php';
echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
```

won't do the job.

Please let me know how I can get access to my session variables.

Comment: You destroy your session on the last line of `contactform`, then try to access it in the very next line.

Comment: run session_start(); then access your session  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstName; this would be place in your second php file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run [session_start](https://www.php.net/session_start) before accessing the `$_SESSION` superglobal array. But your script only run it on the pages where the immediate `$_POST['submit-button']` is set.

Simply move your session_start call to lines before the if-isset statement should fix your issue.

Move your [session_destroy](https://www.php.net/session_destroy) call to somewhere after all necessary `$_SESSION` read is done. Or simply remove it.

Comment: Oh I missed one thing. Why do you run session_destroy right after you set the session variable?

Comment: I thought when redirecting to a new php file it wouldn't close the session. and I wanted to end the session. But after removing it, it worked just fine. So where do I have to close my session? in my first php file or second php file?

Comment: You should end the session when there is no more need to read from it. If there is no need to read from `$_SESSION` after the second file, you should use `session_destroy` somewhere in that file.